# HTML / JS requesting information from user

Tags: javascript, html, paypal

Building a website which can take payments from clients, obviously the payment button from paypal just takes you to a payment link.

What I want is a form before this that takes client information and stores it and then advises they have made a payment once complete.

Is this the correct way of doing it?

- Button is pressed
- New webpage opens which requests client information
- Information is sent to a Database (suggestions on which is easier to setup)
- Client then proceeds to Paypal payment
- Add in check, if payment successful, successful page displayed else failed, the page then advises of next steps.
- Transaction complete

Answer (score 0):

You can use PayPal Express Checkout to work directly with the form and database you create. Simply create your form add the PayPal Express Checkout API calls and create your database.

Below is the information on Express Checkout with the demo site and sample code. 
[Express Checkout Getting Started Guide](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/gs_expresscheckout/)
[Express Checkout How Tos](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec-singleItemPayment-curl-etc/)

[PayPal Demo Portal with Code Samples](https://demo.paypal.com/us/home)

[PayPal Code Wizard](http://devtools-paypal.com/integrationwizard/ecpaypal/code.php) - This will generate sample code for Express Checkout including PayPal Functions.

Below is an image of what the Code Wizard looks like and the list of languages the Code Wizard Supports.

[image]